# How to make my div's shrink dynamically, and not hide certain content?

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I'm not quite how to word what I'm asking. I'm still fairly new to CSS.

Here's some images to explain:
This is what my website's navbar looks at full size.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16240136/stackoverflw/fullsize.png

On the left, we have what it looks like at its smallest,
and on the right, we have what I *want* it to look like at its smallest.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16240136/stackoverflw/smallest.png

Basically, I want those navlinks to start disappearing, but I don't want that zxci text to disappear. Also notice how the navlinks shifted to the right. I think that might be margining, though?

I tried setting .navlinks to display inline-block but that didn't change anything for me. Not sure what to do.

This is my HTML and CSS.. I changed the background color to grey so the contrast is visible, since the background image isn't available

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 background-color: #a8a8a8;
 background-position: 50% 45px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url(assets/dark-bg.jpg);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
div .contentBox {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div .navSpan {
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 45px;
}
div .navLinks {
 height: 45px;
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 min-width: 300px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

div .navLinks p {
 margin-left: 23px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 color: #0066CC;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 display: inline;
 font-weight: bolder;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 18px;
}
div .navContainer  span{
 color: #CCCCCC;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: xx-large;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in 0s;
 -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in 0s;
 -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in 0s;
 -o-transition: all .2s ease-in 0s;
 transition: all .2s ease-in 0s;
 display: inline;
 float: right;
}
div .navLinks a {
 border-bottom-width: thin;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
}
div .navContainer {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 width: 50%;
 min-width: 300px;
 height: 45px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container  {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 min-width: 350px;
}
.content {
 color: #0066CC;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 opacity: 1;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}
a:hover {
 color: #0099CC;
 text-decoration: none;
}


}
div .contentHeader {
 width: 100%;
 display: inline;
}

.backbtn {
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: x-large;
 right: 10.px;
 display: inline;
 text-align: right;
 float: right;
 padding-top: 10px;
 border-style: none;
}
.content img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="navSpan" style="background-color:#000">
     <div class="navContainer">
      <div class="navLinks">
          <p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>
          <p>Empty</p>
          <p>Empty</p>
          <p>Empty</p>
          <p>Empty</p>
          <p>Empty</p>
         </div> <!-- navLinks end -->
        <span class="zxci">ZXCi</span>
        </div> <!-- navContainer end -->
    </div> <!-- navBarFull end -->
  
    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="contentBox">
       <div class="content">
        <center>Site is still under construction. Sorry!</center>
        </div> <!-- content end -->
      </div> <!-- contentBox end -->
     
      <div class="contentBox">
       <div class="content">
        <center>
          <img src="assets/falloutboy-picture.png" alt="falloutboy"/>
        </center>
        </div> <!-- content end -->
      </div> <!-- contentBox end -->
    </div> <!-- container end -->
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, so by moving <span class="zxci">ZXCi</span> up before <div class="navLinks"> I was able to get it to remain visible as the links shrink... But it no longer floats all the way to the right side of the navContainer.

Margin-left auto and margin-right 0 doesn't fix the issue, nor does text allign right...

Comment: Have you tried media screen ? using media screen you can customize it for different viewports.

'@media screen and (max-width:320px) /*for small screen like mobile*/
{
      . /*CSS*/
}

@media screen and (min-width:321px)  /*for screen larger than mobile*/
{
   . /*CSS*/
}'

Comment: I actually removed all of the special media stuff because my intention is to make it scalable across all resolutions. I found the solutions though, I just posted it as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nevermind! I found the solution. It was something relatively simple, I believe.

.navLinks now only has overflow: hidden

.navLinks p now contains position: relative and float: left.

.navContainer span now only contains float: right

I deduced that the reason "ZXCi" was being hidden was that it came AFTER the float: left elements. Thus, when the screen resized, it was the first thing seen that needed to be hidden, and was hidden. So by moving it before all of that in the nav container, it now is the last thing to be cut (and doesn't end up ever being cut by minimum width).

I'm not sure why but it was refusing to allign to the far right of my navbar container div. I was fiddling around with settings and accidentally stumbled upon a working configuration. Considering how few settings are applied, I think it's a good one.

My guess is that there were some conflicting formatting settings somewhere. I don't know. It works like a charm now though. (Also that weird gap as it resized was in fact both margining, and my navbar container's width was set larger than my other container's width)